# AttributeError: 'IBapi' object has no attribute 'nextValidOrderId'

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-api

everyone , I am new user on Interactive Brokers API python. Now, one problem trouble me long time. actually, parts of relevant code on nextValidOrderId is identically implemented on other program. It works very well without any error on  'nextValidOrderId'. However, the problem is that the error happens again and again in this simple program. the code is as below and very simple code

```
import threading
import threading
import time
import pandas as pd
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading
import time

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        #self.order_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[ 'OrderId', 'Symbol', 'Status'])

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        print("NextValidId:", orderId)




def run_loop():
    app.run()

def limitOrder(direction,quantity,lt_price):
    order = Order()
    order.action = direction
    order.orderType = "LMT"
    order.totalQuantity = quantity
    order.lmtPrice = lt_price
    return order

contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'DAX'
contract.secType = 'FUT'
contract.exchange = 'Eurex'
contract.currency = 'EUR'
contract.multiplier=1
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '202312'


app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 23)

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

i=5
while i<10:
    print(  app.reqIds(1))
    time.sleep(2)
    order_id = app.nextValidOrderId
    order_id=app.reqIds(1)
    app.placeOrder(order_id,contract,limitOrder("Buy",1,14000))
    app.order_df

time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Looking at your code, the app reference in run_loop probably is throwing an exception because app (in that context is not defined (you might be ok if you add global app to the function.   I suspect that might be contributing to the error, possibly  because run would never actually be called on the app by the thread.  I am not familiar with the library you are using but seems likely that the reference to the app object is bad in that function.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
order_id = app.nextValidOrderId
```

There is no such property in app object yet, You should call:

```
app.nextValidId(app.reqIds(1))
```

before that line.